# Recommendations for POP3/IMAP software for Windows Server 2003 and migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, pop3

We are currently in the process of migrating websites from a Windows server running Parallels Business Automation to a Windows Server not running Parallels. Can anyone recommend a POP3/IMAP/SMTP software application preferably free that we can use on our new system.

Bonus question: Is there a simple way of migrating existing POP3 accounts/data to a new server from a Parallels Business Automation format, we do not have access to OS in any way, just the Parallels interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Linux world, the best IMAP/POP3 server is [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/). Good migration options, and an offer of 1000euro if you can find a security hole in it! You have a choice of SMTP MTAs too, [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/), [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [Exim](http://www.exim.org/) or Qmail are all good, secure, fast and reliable. Its a pity you can't set up a linux VM just to run your mail services, as I'd recommend that highly.

For Windows, you can have [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) or [MDaemon](http://www.altn.com/). I'm sure there are more if you try google, but in general, the "big names" are the Linux ones and MS Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these a try but you've given me the idea to host the email on my Linux server now! :-)

Comment: Reading some virtualisation platforms, they recommend putting all email on a separate vm guest. It helps isolate the problems and obviously will enhance security and reliability. Next, put the websites in their own VMs too, then the DB, then your 'base services' like ldap. I think most email is still run via Linux tools, which is why they've not been ported to Windows - no demand whatsoever.

Comment: How about trying: http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/121903 ($25per user) or http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1095